# Mercurial : how to recognize partially overlapped histories (fine grain)?

Tags: mercurial, dvcs

How can Mercurial (or any other DVCS) recognize partially overlapped histories? E.g. fine grain / coarse grain.

Is there any way in Mercurial to usefully merge two repositories
where the lines of history are similar, but not identical?

E.g. where one rep has coarse grain revisions 0,1,2 
and the other has fine grain revisions 0, 0.1, 0.2, 1, 1.1, 1.2, 2,
and come up with a single history?

Rather than a mess of branches and heads, which is what I get when I try using what I know of Mercurial?

Or the even fancier
Repo 1: 0, 1, 1.1, 1.2, 2
Repo 2: 0, 0.1, 0.2, 1, 2, 3
Merge: 0, 0.1, 0.2, 1, 1.1, 1.2 2, 3

#### In more detail

What I want is a merge that can recognize when file contents are the same,
or which can recognize that two lines of history are similar, although not all versions in one line
are in the other,
and give something like:

```
o=o changesets with same file contents on different historical lines
o |  (line1) 
| |  changeset:   2:2a02e67e7b5d
| |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:15 2012 -0700
| |  summary:     2
| o  (line2)
| |  changeset:   8:089179dde80a
| |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:15 2012 -0700
| |  summary:     2
| |
| o  changeset:   7:615416921e33
| |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:14 2012 -0700
| |  summary:     1.2
| |
| o  changeset:   6:a43a88065141
| |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:14 2012 -0700
| |  summary:     1.1
| |
| |
o=o changesets with same file contents on different historical lines
o |  (line1) 
| |  changeset:   1:93cbae111269
| |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:13 2012 -0700
| |  summary:     1
| o  (line2) 
| |  changeset:   5:fef4050e0162
| |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:12 2012 -0700
| |  summary:     1
| |
| o  changeset:   4:b51fbedc72e5
| |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:12 2012 -0700
| |  summary:     0.2
| |
| o  changeset:   3:45b7f64b2a23
| |  parent:      0:c80bc10826be
| |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:12 2012 -0700
| |  summary:     0.1
| |
| |
|/
|
o  changeset:   0:c80bc10826be
   user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
   date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:11 2012 -0700
   summary:     0
```

I can imagine that possibly a merge changeset would be necessary at the o=o points.

But I would like to have it recognized automatically.

Here's an example of how such a history would be created.
Contrived in this example, but something siomilar is happening to me in real-life,
when a project wants coarse grain commits, but where I want to preserve the fine grain ciommits
(as well as the coarse grain stuff released to the project).

```
[glew@mipscs587 ~/hack/hg-granularity] 900$ bash 12:39:54>. ./eg

% set verbose

% mkdir hg-repo
% cd hg-repo
% ./hg-repo
% hg init
% echo 0 > a
% hg add a
% hg ci -m0 a

% cd ..
% hg clone hg-repo fine
updating to branch default
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
% hg clone hg-repo coarse
updating to branch default
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved

% cd fine
./fine
% echo 0.1 > a; hg ci -m0.1
% echo 0.2 > a; hg ci -m0.2
% echo 1 > a; hg ci -m1
% cat a
1
% hg push default
pushing to /home/glew/hack/hg-granularity/hg-repo
searching for changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 3 changesets with 3 changes to 1 files
% hg glog
@  changeset:   3:fef4050e0162
|  tag:         tip
|  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
|  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:12 2012 -0700
|  summary:     1
|
o  changeset:   2:b51fbedc72e5
|  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
|  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:12 2012 -0700
|  summary:     0.2
|
o  changeset:   1:45b7f64b2a23
|  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
|  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:12 2012 -0700
|  summary:     0.1
|
o  changeset:   0:c80bc10826be
   user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
   date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:11 2012 -0700
   summary:     0


% cd ../coarse
% cp ../fine/a .
% cat a
1
% hg ci -m1
% hg glog
@  changeset:   1:93cbae111269
|  tag:         tip
|  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
|  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:13 2012 -0700
|  summary:     1
|
o  changeset:   0:c80bc10826be
   user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
   date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:11 2012 -0700
   summary:     0


% cd ../fine
% echo 1.1 > a; hg ci -m1.1
% echo 1.2 > a; hg ci -m1.2
% echo 2 > a; hg ci -m2
% cat a
2
% hg push default
pushing to /home/glew/hack/hg-granularity/hg-repo
searching for changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 3 changesets with 3 changes to 1 files
% hg glog
@  changeset:   6:089179dde80a
|  tag:         tip
|  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
|  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:15 2012 -0700
|  summary:     2
|
o  changeset:   5:615416921e33
|  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
|  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:14 2012 -0700
|  summary:     1.2
|
o  changeset:   4:a43a88065141
|  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
|  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:14 2012 -0700
|  summary:     1.1
|
o  changeset:   3:fef4050e0162
|  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
|  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:12 2012 -0700
|  summary:     1
|
o  changeset:   2:b51fbedc72e5
|  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
|  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:12 2012 -0700
|  summary:     0.2
|
o  changeset:   1:45b7f64b2a23
|  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
|  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:12 2012 -0700
|  summary:     0.1
|
o  changeset:   0:c80bc10826be
   user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
   date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:11 2012 -0700
   summary:     0


% cd ../coarse
% cp ../fine/a .
% cat a
2
% hg ci -m2
% hg glog
@  changeset:   2:2a02e67e7b5d
|  tag:         tip
|  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
|  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:15 2012 -0700
|  summary:     2
|
o  changeset:   1:93cbae111269
|  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
|  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:13 2012 -0700
|  summary:     1
|
o  changeset:   0:c80bc10826be
   user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
   date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:11 2012 -0700
   summary:     0
```

OK, so now I have a fine grain history in the fine repo,
and a coarse grain history in the coarse repo.  I wouldf like to merge them.
(Firget that the coarse is a subset of the fine: I can easily contrive exanples where they are not).

Simply pushing the coarse grain history gives a warning.
I will opush it later,
but first I will try merging in a separate clone.

```
% hg push default
pushing to /home/glew/hack/hg-granularity/hg-repo
searching for changes
abort: push creates new remote head 2a02e67e7b5d!
(you should pull and merge or use push -f to force)

% cd ..

% hg clone coarse merge-fine-and-coarse
updating to branch default
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
% cd merge-fine-and-coarse/
./merge-fine-and-coarse/


% hg glog
@  changeset:   2:2a02e67e7b5d
|  tag:         tip
|  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
|  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:15 2012 -0700
|  summary:     2
|
o  changeset:   1:93cbae111269
|  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
|  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:13 2012 -0700
|  summary:     1
|
o  changeset:   0:c80bc10826be
   user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
   date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:11 2012 -0700
   summary:     0



% hg pull ../hg-repo
pulling from ../hg-repo
searching for changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 6 changesets with 6 changes to 1 files (+1 heads)
(run 'hg heads' to see heads, 'hg merge' to merge)


% hg heads
changeset:   8:089179dde80a
tag:         tip
user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:15 2012 -0700
summary:     2

changeset:   2:2a02e67e7b5d
user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:15 2012 -0700
summary:     2
```

Here is the merge.

Notice that the pairs
    o  changeset:   8:089179dde80a
    | @  changeset:   2:2a02e67e7b5d
and
    o  changeset:   5:fef4050e0162
    | o  changeset:   1:93cbae111269
have the same file contents,
one from the coartse and the other from the fine repo.
But the Mercurial history graph does not reflect this.

```
% hg glog
o  changeset:   8:089179dde80a
|  tag:         tip
|  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
|  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:15 2012 -0700
|  summary:     2
|
o  changeset:   7:615416921e33
|  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
|  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:14 2012 -0700
|  summary:     1.2
|
o  changeset:   6:a43a88065141
|  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
|  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:14 2012 -0700
|  summary:     1.1
|
o  changeset:   5:fef4050e0162
|  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
|  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:12 2012 -0700
|  summary:     1
|
o  changeset:   4:b51fbedc72e5
|  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
|  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:12 2012 -0700
|  summary:     0.2
|
o  changeset:   3:45b7f64b2a23
|  parent:      0:c80bc10826be
|  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
|  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:12 2012 -0700
|  summary:     0.1
|
| @  changeset:   2:2a02e67e7b5d
| |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:15 2012 -0700
| |  summary:     2
| |
| o  changeset:   1:93cbae111269
|/   user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
|    date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:13 2012 -0700
|    summary:     1
|
o  changeset:   0:c80bc10826be
   user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
   date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:11 2012 -0700
   summary:     0


% hg diff -r 2a02e67e7b5d -r 089179dde80a
```

So I'll try a merge

```
% hg merge -r 8
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
(branch merge, don't forget to commit)


% hg ci -m'merge of fine and coarse at 2'
```

Better - 
this shows that 
    o  changeset:   8:089179dde80a
    | @  changeset:   2:2a02e67e7b5d
are a convergence point,
although an extra dummy changesrt was necessary.

But it does not show the commonality between
    o  changeset:   5:fef4050e0162
    | o  changeset:   1:93cbae111269

Here's the merged graph

```
% hg glog
@    changeset:   9:328db8187d31
|\   tag:         tip
| |  parent:      2:2a02e67e7b5d
| |  parent:      8:089179dde80a
| |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:43:51 2012 -0700
| |  summary:     merge of fine and coarse at 2
| |
| o  changeset:   8:089179dde80a
| |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:15 2012 -0700
| |  summary:     2
| |
| o  changeset:   7:615416921e33
| |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:14 2012 -0700
| |  summary:     1.2
| |
| o  changeset:   6:a43a88065141
| |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:14 2012 -0700
| |  summary:     1.1
| |
| o  changeset:   5:fef4050e0162
| |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:12 2012 -0700
| |  summary:     1
| |
| o  changeset:   4:b51fbedc72e5
| |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:12 2012 -0700
| |  summary:     0.2
| |
| o  changeset:   3:45b7f64b2a23
| |  parent:      0:c80bc10826be
| |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:12 2012 -0700
| |  summary:     0.1
| |
o |  changeset:   2:2a02e67e7b5d
| |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:15 2012 -0700
| |  summary:     2
| |
o |  changeset:   1:93cbae111269
|/   user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
|    date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:13 2012 -0700
|    summary:     1
|
o  changeset:   0:c80bc10826be
   user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
   date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:11 2012 -0700
   summary:     0
```

How about another merge?

```
% hg update -r 1
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved


% hg merge -r 5
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
(branch merge, don't forget to commit)


% hg ci -m'merge of fine and coarse at 1'
created new head


% hg glog
@    changeset:   10:cca7fec90d3f
|\   tag:         tip
| |  parent:      1:93cbae111269
| |  parent:      5:fef4050e0162
| |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:45:03 2012 -0700
| |  summary:     merge of fine and coarse at 1
| |
| | o    changeset:   9:328db8187d31
| | |\   parent:      2:2a02e67e7b5d
| | | |  parent:      8:089179dde80a
| | | |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| | | |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:43:51 2012 -0700
| | | |  summary:     merge of fine and coarse at 2
| | | |
| | | o  changeset:   8:089179dde80a
| | | |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| | | |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:15 2012 -0700
| | | |  summary:     2
| | | |
| | | o  changeset:   7:615416921e33
| | | |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| | | |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:14 2012 -0700
| | | |  summary:     1.2
| | | |
| +---o  changeset:   6:a43a88065141
| | |    user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| | |    date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:14 2012 -0700
| | |    summary:     1.1
| | |
| o |  changeset:   5:fef4050e0162
| | |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| | |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:12 2012 -0700
| | |  summary:     1
| | |
| o |  changeset:   4:b51fbedc72e5
| | |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| | |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:12 2012 -0700
| | |  summary:     0.2
| | |
| o |  changeset:   3:45b7f64b2a23
| | |  parent:      0:c80bc10826be
| | |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| | |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:12 2012 -0700
| | |  summary:     0.1
| | |
+---o  changeset:   2:2a02e67e7b5d
| |    user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| |    date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:15 2012 -0700
| |    summary:     2
| |
o |  changeset:   1:93cbae111269
|/   user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
|    date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:13 2012 -0700
|    summary:     1
|
o  changeset:   0:c80bc10826be
   user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
   date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:11 2012 -0700
   summary:     0
```

This is not right.  It has established a new head, whereas 
what we wanted was some way of indicating that
    o  changeset:   5:fef4050e0162
    | o  changeset:   1:93cbae111269
are the same.

OK, switch back to the original coarse

```
% cd ../coarse


% hg push default
pushing to /home/glew/hack/hg-granularity/hg-repo
searching for changes
abort: push creates new remote head 2a02e67e7b5d!
(you should pull and merge or use push -f to force)


% hg push -f default
pushing to /home/glew/hack/hg-granularity/hg-repo
searching for changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 2 changesets with 2 changes to 1 files (+1 heads)


% hg glog
@  changeset:   2:2a02e67e7b5d
|  tag:         tip
|  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
|  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:15 2012 -0700
|  summary:     2
|
o  changeset:   1:93cbae111269
|  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
|  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:13 2012 -0700
|  summary:     1
|
o  changeset:   0:c80bc10826be
   user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
   date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:11 2012 -0700
   summary:     0



% cd ../hg-repo/


% hg glog
o  changeset:   8:2a02e67e7b5d
|  tag:         tip
|  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
|  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:15 2012 -0700
|  summary:     2
|
o  changeset:   7:93cbae111269
|  parent:      0:c80bc10826be
|  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
|  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:13 2012 -0700
|  summary:     1
|
| o  changeset:   6:089179dde80a
| |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:15 2012 -0700
| |  summary:     2
| |
| o  changeset:   5:615416921e33
| |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:14 2012 -0700
| |  summary:     1.2
| |
| o  changeset:   4:a43a88065141
| |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:14 2012 -0700
| |  summary:     1.1
| |
| o  changeset:   3:fef4050e0162
| |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:12 2012 -0700
| |  summary:     1
| |
| o  changeset:   2:b51fbedc72e5
| |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:12 2012 -0700
| |  summary:     0.2
| |
| o  changeset:   1:45b7f64b2a23
|/   user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
|    date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:12 2012 -0700
|    summary:     0.1
|
@  changeset:   0:c80bc10826be
   user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
   date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:11 2012 -0700
   summary:     0



% echo This is not right
This is not right
```

What I want is a merge that can recognize when file contents are the same,
or which can recognize that two lines of history are similar, although not all versions in one line
are in the other,
and give something like:

```
o=o changesets with same file contents on different historical lines
o |  (line1) 
| |  changeset:   2:2a02e67e7b5d
| |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:15 2012 -0700
| |  summary:     2
| o  (line2)
| |  changeset:   8:089179dde80a
| |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:15 2012 -0700
| |  summary:     2
| |
| o  changeset:   7:615416921e33
| |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:14 2012 -0700
| |  summary:     1.2
| |
| o  changeset:   6:a43a88065141
| |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:14 2012 -0700
| |  summary:     1.1
| |
| |
o=o changesets with same file contents on different historical lines
o |  (line1) 
| |  changeset:   1:93cbae111269
| |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:13 2012 -0700
| |  summary:     1
| o  (line2) 
| |  changeset:   5:fef4050e0162
| |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:12 2012 -0700
| |  summary:     1
| |
| o  changeset:   4:b51fbedc72e5
| |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:12 2012 -0700
| |  summary:     0.2
| |
| o  changeset:   3:45b7f64b2a23
| |  parent:      0:c80bc10826be
| |  user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
| |  date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:12 2012 -0700
| |  summary:     0.1
| |
| |
|/
|
o  changeset:   0:c80bc10826be
   user:        Andy Glew <glew@mips.com>
   date:        Thu Jun 21 12:40:11 2012 -0700
   summary:     0
```

I can imagine that possibly a merge changeset would be necessary at the o=o points.

But I would like to have it recognized automatically.

Heck, forget "recognized".  I would like to have a way that I can recognize it manually, but have it represented in Mercurial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Mercurial can get the design pattern you are looking for.  Mercurial tracks the difference from a parent changeset to a child changeset so it doesn't really care about the contents of a file as a whole.  Even if your file at revision 2 on tree A and the file at revision 5 on tree B have the same contents they were descended from different parents and thus have a different way of storing how they were changed.  I haven't looked too much into the mq extension but that is the only thing I can think of that can edit a tree's history enough to do what you want.  Editing a tree's history is always a dangerous thing to do and it is rarely recommended.

Edit:
I'm not too sure on this one either but the rebase extension might work for you as well.

Comment: Thanks. This is pretty much what I figured, but I thought it might be worth asking. Since it is often as important to know what you CANNOT do as what you CAN do, I'll mark this answered in a few days, unless some genius shows up and tells me how to do it.